# Contact form 7 conditional fields

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have some product in a page which are subpages. When user clicks Order, it pops up a form which user fills in and sends. I have around 20 products in the page and each of them has the form with almost same fields, except a couple of different fields. So, in general each item has 5 common fields. And then 1-2 additional fields for some products. How can I use one base form and add conditional fields to some? 
Is it possible to just create dynamic html form in the loop and send it via contact form 7? If not, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: CF7 provides form functionality, it won't make sense to create custom form and then send it via CF7 that is only if you could.

Comment: A better way would be to create custom forms and then send it via `wp_mail`. If you want to save the form data, just insert each form data as a **custom post type**.

Comment: I guess creating custom form is the best way then.